# 仮想マシンの処理能力の比較方法が分からない

Tags: network

こちらの画像の空欄aがわかりません。

なぜ
三枚目の表では
A,Bは①の計算処理能力で計算して、C,Dは②のネットワーク処理能力 で計算して比較しているのでしょうか？？？？？？？？

(C,Dも同じ計算処理能力で計算した方が良いと思ったのですが)[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: また質問文は画像ではなくできるだけテキストでかきましょう。ポイントは解説にある。「システム全体の処理量は、①、②で値の小さいほうの5です」という部分でしょう

Comment: わかりました。　「システム全体の処理量は、①、②で値の小さいほうの5です」...とは...

Comment: そこの意味がわからないのであれば質問するべきポイントはそこです。「なぜ計算処理能力とネットワーク処理能力を計算して小さいほうを採用するのか」そこにしぼってもう一度質問を編集してみてください

Comment: ちなみにその文章は解説を抜き出しているだけです。解説文をきちんと読んでみてください

Comment: 計算処理量とネットワーク処理量をくらべて小さな方で比較しているから、ですね。わかって来ました、ありがとうございますm(_ _)m

Comment: 画像に映っている書名から技術評論社から出版されている書籍の様ですが、問題文以外の解説の部分には著作権が発生しているのではないかと思います。引用(著作権法第32条第1項)の範囲なのかもしれませんが、注意喚起しておきます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

計算処理量とネットワーク処理量とを比べて低い方がシステム全体の処理量である。
その為に、①と②を比べて低い方で比較しあっている。